# r blogdown - build_site result does not matched preview from serve_site

Tags: r, blogdown

I create a new blog with blogdown, but somehow i seem to make a mistake as the
site i built does not match the preview from `serve_site`.

```
dir.create("blog7")
setwd("blog7")
blogdown::new_site(theme = "shenoybr/hugo-goa")
blogdown::serve_site()
blogdown::build_site()
browseURL(url = "public/index.html")
```

The links do not work as expected and the image is not shown.
The image seems to work if i change: `/img/headshot.jpg` to `./img/headshot.jpg`. The links dont seem to be relative.

How can i avoid These issues to appear and avoid editing the result in `public` manually?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have some problem with `baseURL` settings in [`config.toml`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/configuration.html).

- When running `blogdown::serve_site()`, baseURL setting is overriden by `"/"` to be served locally under localhost.
- For `blogdown::build_site()` you need to set up a real base URL of your blog (i.e. `"https://www.example.com/"`) or at least `"/"`.

Note that if you build your site with `blogdown::build_site()` and some settings and then try to open that HTML from local `public` folder, it will not work as expected. Just because the URLs are built from `baseURL` and point e.g. to `/img/headshot.jpg` (which does not make sense locally, but works well on the web like `https://blog.example.com/img/headshot.jpg`.

So:

- if you want to preview your site locally with localhost, use `blogdown::serve_site()`,
- for exporting the site to the web, use `blogdown::build_site()`, but note that those generated HTML files will not work properly when running locally.

See more details in the [book about blogdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/local-preview.html) and some [info about `config.toml`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/configuration.html).

Comment: @Tlatwork Great, I'm glad it works for you. :-) Don't worry, particularly this I'm facing very often - as I'm usually used to create websites manually with HTML. So when I occasionaly use blogdown and open HTML from public folder, it does not work, of course. :-)